# Why are some functions not supported by my shell?

Tags: c, linux, shell, mkdir, fork

I am experimenting with writing a simple shell to support all the usual functions.

So far, despite my haphazard approach to it, I have been met with success - I have been able to fork() new processes with parameters but other certain methods don't seem to run.

When I run my shell, functions like pwd, ls, help work whilst other functions such as cd, mkdir don't - why is this & what research/investigation can I do in order to begin to address this?

I've included my code so far (although I'm not sure if it will actually help).

Thanks very much

EDIT: My output, when my shell is running in cygwin, if I type "cd /cygdrive/c" the output is "Command not found"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const int MAX_ARGS = 9;

size_t nBytes = 64; //Data type representing size of objects (unsigned)
int bytesRead = -1;
char *cmd = NULL;
char prompt[] = "DaSh-> ";
int argc;
char **argv;
int pid;
int childpid;
int status;

void process();
int readcmd();

int main() {

    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    while (1) {
        bytesRead = -1;
        printf(prompt);
        while (bytesRead == -1) {
            bytesRead = readcmd();
        }

        process(cmd); //process the single line input into arguments

        if (strcmp(argv[0], "exit") == 0) { //If user types exit
            exit(0);
        }

        childpid = fork();

        if (childpid == 0) { //This is run by the child
            execvp(argv[0], argv);
            printf("Command not recognised\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        else if (childpid > 0 ) {
            waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
        }

    }

    return 0;
}

int nrows = 10;
int ncolumns = 2;


void process(char argStr[]) {
    argv = malloc(MAX_ARGS * sizeof(char *)); //Array of pointers to the char first letter of each argument
    char delims[] = " \n"; //Delimit about space

    int i = 0;
    argv[i] = strtok(argStr, delims);
    while (argv[i] != NULL) {
        argv[++i] = strtok( NULL, delims);
    }

    argc = i;

}

int readcmd() {
    return getline(&cmd, &nBytes, stdin);
}
```

Comment: cd and mkdir are internal to the shell.  You would have to implement their functionality in your shell to make them work.

Comment: `cd` is internal to a shell, and has to be -like `ulimit`- (since each process has its own current directory, so if you forked a process the `chdir` would apply only to that process, not to the invoking shell), but `mkdir` is the `/bin/mkdir` program, and you don't need to make it a builtin (except for performance reasons).

Comment: You really should test and debug your shell on Linux not in cygwin. You depend upon Linux [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) which Cygwin is not able to perfectly simulate. Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)